# Machine Learning Sololearn's Coach Problem about Coulmn data etc

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Problem:

**Machine Learning - What's in a Column?**

*Getting a column from a numpy array.*

**Task -**
Given a csv file and a column name, print the elements in the given column.

**Input Format -**
First line: filename of a csv file ;
Second line: column name

**Output Format -**
Numpy array

**Sample Input -**
'usercode/files/one.csv' (*filename*) ;
'a' (*colmn name*)

**File 'one.csv' contents:**

a,b

1,3

2,4

**Sample Output  -**
[1 2]

**----------**

**My Answer :**

```
import pandas as p 
df = p.read_csv('usercode/files/one.csv')

details = df[['a', 'b']].values

print(details[:,1])
```

**But,**

I think it needs output **[1,2]** and **[3,4]** some how, that it satisfy both *Case 1* and *Case 2* at the same time. My code can't do so. If I satisfy *Case 1*, *Case 2* isn't satisfied and vice-versa

[image]

Comment: I guess you should read both the filename and the required column name from the input file (you hard coded the filename instead and don't use the column name at all). If you then have the column name in a variable `col_name` you can select the column by `df[col_name].to_numpy()`, see here for an introduction to pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html

Comment: Note that the `.values` property is being deprecated in favour of `.to_numpy()`. [Ref here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html).

Comment: can you give a coding reference to it.....I mean can you give an actual solution to the above problem...modified code of mine ? Plssss !!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd


filename = input()
column_name = input()

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
arr = df[column_name].values

print(arr)
```

filename and column_name are arguments that user will input and just write those arguments inside the function you can get the answer.